# Reporting services partially colored cell

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can i create partialy colored cell in reporting services table or matrix? For example: I hava value of 45& i want to fill only 45% of cell with red color, and other 55% stay white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can see that working is to have a background image that is x% full of red for each percentage band you want to show. 
Then you can set an expression to fill the background with the correct image depending on the value of a particular field.

Not quite the greatest solution as you are going to need 20 images just to get 5% bands.

The other option is to write a webservice/asp.net page that will generate an image in the correct proportions based on a querystring. Then you can set the background image to the aspx page.
[This article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/generating-asp-net-images-fly) is an example of how to create an image on the fly through asp.net

Tested the following code and it works quite nicely to produce an in cell chart.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int percent = 0;
        int height = 20;

        if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("percent"))
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["percent"], out percent);
        }

        if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("height"))
        {
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["height"], out height);
        }

        Bitmap respBitmap = new Bitmap(100, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(respBitmap);
        Brush brsh = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        graphics.FillRectangle(brsh, new Rectangle(0, 0, respBitmap.Width, respBitmap.Height));

        brsh = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        graphics.FillRectangle(brsh, new Rectangle(0, 0, respBitmap.Width * percent / 100, respBitmap.Height));

        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.Charset = "";
        respBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }
```

Go to the text box you want, change the BackGroundImage source to external and the value to an expression.
Use an expression something like

```
= "http://mysite/chartimage.aspx?percentage=" & Fields!MyField.Value
```

Comment: Is this possible on some other way?

Comment: Its ok to create image, but how to set column in reporting services (.rdlc) to render that image, i am probably missing someting?

Comment: The background image property lets you select source: external, value:expression